# How to change consitency mode to Stale in Spring Cloud consul config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-consul

Consul supports consistency mode param in http . As per consul documentation it can have DEFAULT,CONSISTENT,STALE . I want to change the consistency mode from default ot STALE in one of my application. I didn't find any way in the provided spring documentation. Is this achievable using spring cloud consul config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your use case is only to start consul after only one stayed up. You can use this hack, and then call it from Spring boot main method.

```
public static void changeConsistencyModeToStale() {
    for (Field field : QueryParams.class.getFields()) {
        if ("DEFAULT".equals(field.getName())) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
                modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
                modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
                field.set(null, new QueryParams(ConsistencyMode.STALE));
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                log.error("Error while try to set stale mode to consul", e);
            }

            log.info("Consistence mode has been set to stale successfully");
        }
    }
}
```